# Is there a way to annotate a value as non-zero in C?

Tags: c, optimization, annotations

This is mostly theoretical as I haven't benchmarked or anything, but I have code like this:

```c
for(ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < page_count; i++) {
    Page* page = pages[i];
    uint32_t entry_count = page->entry_count;
    // clang adds check here
    for(ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < entry_count; j++) {
        // stuff
    }
}
```

I know statically that every page will always have at least one entry. However, clang is inserting the equivalent of `if (entry_count == 0) return` before entering the nested loop. I realize the branch predictor will quickly learn to ignore that branch, but that got me wondering: is there a way to indicate to the compiler that I know `entry_count` is non-zero? Adding an assertion manually results in a runtime check anyway, so it doesn't buy much.

I found the `nonnull` attribute, but nothing for values.

Comment: C23 will add `unreachable()`. So you could insert `if (entry_count == 0) unreachable();` to inform the compiler that `entry_count` is non-zero.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`__builtin_assume`](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-functions) is made for that. However, note that:

> If the condition is violated during execution, the behavior is undefined

Alternatively, you can rewrite the code so that the condition is not done:

```cpp
for(ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < page_count; i++) {
    Page* page = pages[i];
    uint32_t entry_count = page->entry_count;
    ptrdiff_t j = 0;
    do {
        // stuff
        j++;
    } while(j < entry_count);
}
```

This solution is more portable (compiler independent) but harder to read (and so harder to maintain).

Comment: UV for a good `do` solution.  DV for harder to read than a `for()` loop with some sort of _ignore first test_.  It is what OP wants and needs.